# jmespath search nested array issue

Tags: python, jmespath

I need to search all dict in a nested array as below by its key with `jmespath`

```
my_list = [[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'james'}], [{'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]]
```

I got an empty list with jmespath search: `jmespath.search("[][?name=='kobe']", my_list)`

how can I get result: `[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]` with jmespath search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following jmesQuery:

```
[]|[?name=='kobe']
```

on input:

```
[[{"age": 1, "name": "kobe"}, {"age": 2, "name": "james"}], [{"age": 3, "name": "kobe"}]]
```

to get output:

```
[
  {
    "age": 1,
    "name": "kobe"
  },
  {
    "age": 3,
    "name": "kobe"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a mix of different types, that is why you don't get expected results.

What you should do is this:

```
jmespath.search("[].to_array(@)[?name=='kobe'][]", my_list)
```

Here is a break down using Python console (pay attention to :

```
>>> my_list
[[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'james'}], [{'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]]

>>> jmespath.search("[]", my_list)
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'james'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]

>>> jmespath.search("[].to_array(@)", my_list)
[[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}], [{'age': 2, 'name': 'james'}], [{'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]]

>>> jmespath.search("[].to_array(@)[]", my_list)
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'james'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]

>>> jmespath.search("[].to_array(@)[?name=='kobe']", my_list)
[[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}], [], [{'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]]

>>> jmespath.search("[].to_array(@)[?name=='kobe'][]", my_list)
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]
```

You can find more explanation with examples in this guide: https://www.doaws.pl/blog/2021-12-05-how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes/how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes

Answer (score -1):

Use Below code:

```
my_list = [[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'james'}], [{'age': 3, 
'name': 'kobe'}]]

for l in my_list:
    for dictionary in l:
        Value_List = dictionary.values()
        if "kobe" in Value_List:
            print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}
{'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}
```

OR-----

```
my_list = [[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'james'}], 
          [{'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]]
Match_List = []
for l in my_list:
    for dictionary in l:
        if dictionary["name"] == "kobe":
            Match_List.append(dictionary)
print(Match_List)
```

Output:

```
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'kobe'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'kobe'}]
```

Comment: thank you, but I have to get the result by jmespath search